# How to filter realm objects by date field in javascript?

Tags: javascript, realm

`Relam` has a `filtered` method to filter the results. One of my fields is type of `date` and I want to filter result by that and this is my code but I got the error `Error: Invalid predicate: 'createdAt >= Sat Jul 23 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0430 (+0430)': syntax error, unexpected identifier, expecting end of file`

```
const realm = useRealm();
const checkLists = realm.objects("DoneCheck");
const todayFirstDay = new Date('2020-02-02'); //for example
const matchedCheckList = checkLists.filtered(`createdAt >= ${todayFirstDay}`);
```

and also this is my table schema :

```
static schema = {
  name: "DoneCheck",
  primaryKey: "_id",
  properties: {
    _id: "string",
    checkListId: "string",
    createdAt: "date",
  },
};
```

Comment: Instead of `>=`, try `=>`